# Getting ID of item after posting to a document library

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, wcf-data-services, odata

I'm currently consuming information from Sharepoint 2010 using WCF Data Services from C# (an asp.net mvc4 application).

With regular Sharepoint lists items, when saving the changes to the context, the id of the new item is automatically populated on the original object. Meaning:

```
SomeContext context = /* creation of the context*/;
var someEntity = new SomeEntity {...};
context.AddToSomeEntityItems(someEntity);
context.SaveChanges();
var newId = someEntity.Id;      //this will have the new id
```

However, if what you are creating is an item for a document library, the id doesn't seem to be updated on the saved entity. For example:

```
SomeContext context = /* creation of the context*/;
var someOtherEntity = new SomeOtherEntity {...};
Stream data = /* some stream*/;
context.AddToSomeOtherEntityItems(someOtherEntity);
context.SetSaveStream(someOtherEntity, data, true, "SomeMIMEType", "SomeSlugPath");
context.SaveChanges();
var newId = someOtherEntity.Id;         //this will instead always have 0
```

I initially thought this was a bug in the first version of WCF Data Services so I updated to the latest, [5.4.0](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client/5.4.0). But the behavior seems to be the same.

I would prefer to have to avoid strange lookups that ultimately could fail during heavy load, such as using `.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).First()` to get the recently created item.

When looking at the actual network traffic using Fiddler, I can see that the initial upload of the binary data actually does return the information for the item along with its ID. And if I configure other relationships to that item using [SetLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.setlink%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) prior to saving changes they are linked correctly, so the context does handle the value accordingly.

Is there any way to get WCF Data Services to update the ID on the entity when the item is for a document library?

Comment: Wow, am I really the only one using WCF Data Services for a scenario with data streams?

Comment: what is a valid slug path in this scenario? i keep getting errors when i try and do this but i dont get any info about what is causing the error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35523373/adding-items-to-sharepoint-document-library-with-web-service

Answer (score 2):

Typically, I set the Id manually *before* inserting it with

```
someOtherEntity.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
```

That way you can TDD it more easily as well. I think it is best to leave the responsibilities to your code than to rely upon an external storage system to tell you what the Id is.

Comment: That won't work in this scenario. In this case the data is managed by Sharepoint and Sharepoint assigns its own IDs. Plus I can't change the current data model plus open it up to concurrency issues and duplicate ids. 
The current one works flawlessly in every other scenario, except when streams are involved, which is why I'm looking for a way to get it to work with the automatic IDs AND streams.
The behavior may indicate that it might be a bug on the WCF Client or Sharepoint's server implementation, but I haven't found any information that would indicate that.

Answer (score 2):

What I am doing is parsing out the id from the response headers:

```
var responses = context.SaveChanges();
var created = responses.FirstOrDefault(r => r.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Created);

if (response != null)
{
    var location = response.Headers.First(h => h.Key == "Location").Value;
    //location will be http://sharepoint.url/site/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/{listname}(id)
    //you can parse out the id from the end of that string
}
```

It's not exactly elegant, but it works.

Comment: Interesting workaround! I'll leave the question open in case somebody from the data services team identifies the bug and comments on it. Thanks for the workaround.

Comment: I've seen all kinds of ways that this is supposed to function, either using the preferences or with a wrapper of SaveChanges that does some extra stuff, but nothing worked for me except this. It might feel a bit kludgy but it should be just as reliable as anything with how data services works..